# New model attribute issues after heroku deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, model, attributes, migration

I had a company model and I added a keywords attribute to this model using:
    rails generate migration add_keywors_to_companies keywords:text
After running the migration and changing the form I was able to edit and create new companies with the keywords attribute. After deploying onto heroku, however, when i make changes to an existing company the keywords attribute does not get saved. Also when i try to add a new company, the app errors.

I have already run: heroku run rake db:migrate

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the error from your server log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app does not reload after migrations, simply

heroku ps:restart --app myapp